# Intel HD 2000 video card only 640x480 in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, drivers, graphics, intel-graphics, display-resolution

First time installing anything but Windows, and have run into the following problem:

- When I ran the Ubuntu installation, I got the odd unintelligible vertical and horizontal lines instead of the installation utility displaying on the monitor. I got around that by F6 and selecting nomodeset.
- Now that I have Ubuntu 14.04 LTS installed, I cannot seem to be able to alter the resolution from 640x480. Screen looks like this:

[image]

- The All Setting --> Details entry for graphics reads "Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe" where I believe it should read Intel Sandybridge (I have an integrated Intel HD 2000 card)
- Software & Updates --> Additional Drivers says "no additional drivers available"
- I've tried the Intel Graphics Installer for Linux with no luck
- I've tried installing the mesautils and that too didn't work

The computer is a Gateway SX2855-UB22P i3 3.1GHz 4GB RAM 1TB HDD with DVDRW.  As I mentioned above, the integrated graphics card is an Intel HD 2000 with dual VGA and HDMI outputs, both of which worked fine until Windows failed and I decided to switch to Ubuntu.

Comment: What is the output of `xrandr`

Answer (score 0):

You need to purge the intel graphics installer from your system using the following command in a terminal   --   sudo apt-get purge intel-linux-graphics-installer && sudo apt-get autoremove  --           Shut down system and restart.    If that does not fix the problem I recommend doing a fresh clean install of UBUNTU 14.04, after fresh install do not install the Intel graphics installer, that installer was only to be used in a couple of previous versions of linux and not to be used in UBUNTU 14.04, it can cause you alot of problems, also DO NOT install (mesautils), which can also cause you problems with resolution. After your fresh install, let UBUNTU install the correct driver for your system. Also when you copy and paste above command do not use the (--) in the command they are only there to seperate. I am also using a gateway DX 4860 computer which is a newer system but with the same i3 chip and onboard graphics and this worked for me.